# Big Data Performance

Tags: javascript, html, performance-testing

Anyone know which occupies less memory and less CPU?

Option 1: binary save several images in data: base64 within several html tags.
Option 2: binary save several images in data: base64 in a javascript array.

Not if the javascript engine will consume more memory or not the same html tag in the subject of the DOM and everything.

I would use HTML5 Storage but is still very new, the normal versions of firefox and chrome does not support them as I know, only the last.

Anyone know?

Comment: And where do you want to store it then? I'm missing context.

Comment: In the HTML or JavaScript: <div class="thumb" data-big="data:image/jpeg;base64,..... or <script>var images[1] = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,....'; ... sorry but I can not better explain the context because they do not speak English, I find it too.

Comment: what html5 storage tech only works in newer copies of firefox+chrome? firefox has had localStorage for over 5 years now...

Comment: a website was saying otherwise. If I save the binary data of an image I can save memory localStorage have him look into a variable?